# Django: strategy for preventing duplicate object creation

Tags: javascript, python, django, asynchronous

I'm running into an issue of creating multiple DB objects when I only ever expect one.

My application models consist of a `Form` with a collection of `Fields`, and a `FormEntry` with a collection of `FieldEntries`. For a given `FormEntry`, I only expect one `FieldEntry` per field.

Here's my problem: my UI uses ajax to submit field entries. the Django code that handles submissions does a `FieldEntry.objects.get_or_create()` to make an entry, but it seems I have some kind of race condition: if two ajax calls fire in rapid succession (they fire as soon as a field loses focus), it seems the second `get_or_create()` can happen before the first has completed, creating two objects. I have added code to clean up after a race, but if the field doesn't get updated again, the code won't be run. To be fair, I'm not sure this is even the mechanism leading to my multiple creation problem.

The question is how best to prevent this? I could implement some kind of resource lock in JS to make sure a field update doesn't occur until a previous update on the same field is finished, but I don't know how to gracefully 'delay' in JS until the lock becomes available.

I could also implement the lock in Django/python, but I think that's even more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) option inside your `FieldEntry` class:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ("form", "field")
```

Comment: Why, that sounds like exactly what I need! I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: +1 for 'rtfd.' Raises an IntegrityError when I try to add a dupe, as far as I'm concerned this is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your model field definition set [unique=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique)

`my_field = models.ForeignKey('any_model', unique=True)`

This will make sure no duplicates entries for `any_model`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't easily post all the code in question, but this won't work. The `FieldEntry` model contains a foreign key to each of `Field` and `FormEntry` - field for structure, and formentry to keep track of which entry it belongs to. I can't enforce unique=true, since there will be many `FieldEntries` referencing a single `FormEntry` (ideally unique within that group on `Field`), and many `FieldEntries` referencing a single `Field` (ideally unique within that group on `FormEntry`)

Answer (score 0):

In `models.py`
Create your model and add `unique=True`

e.g.

```
model_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique= True)
```